# AWS IAM policy, user should see only s3 public buckets

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

i have tried several methods, couldn't succeed. I need to have policy that attach to users, so that they could see only public buckets not all the buckets in their aws console

Comment: See where? In AWS console? can you be more specific? What did you try?

Comment: sry, to specify that, yes in the user aws console

Answer (score 0):

The ability to view a list of buckets is granted via the `s3:ListAllMyBuckets` permission, which is [defined](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/service-authorization/latest/reference/list_amazons3.html) as:

> Grants permission to list all buckets owned by the authenticated sender of the request

Thus, the user either has permission to list the names of **all buckets**, or **none of the buckets**. It is not possible to filter *which* buckets are returned in the listing.